# How can I print an up- or down-arrow right beside a table

Tags: tables, arrows

[image]

I am a beginner and tried using this [table-maker](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) but it's internal columns would not work.

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you've tried in the form of a small document we can compile to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please always try to use a descriptive title. Titles like "how can I do this" are not descriptive and more or less could be used for every of the ¼ Mio. questions here, but shouldn't because they are useless.

Comment: And please always explain in the text of the questions, what your problem is. The two tables are nothing special and can be reached using `tabular` (either using `l|c|c|`, `r|c|c`, or `c|c|c` as column specification). Every LaTeX introduction shows such tables. Vertical arrows can be printed using a `picture` environment (very basic), TikZ (maybe in addition with package `tikzmark`), or PSTricks. There should be enough questions about these. So please explain your problem and [make it reproducible](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964).

Comment: How to draw such an arrow depends on how you typeset the table. Different packages for tables exist and there are different approaches to this depending on the package you use. So, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows how the above tables (one of them is enough) are generated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `nicematrix` package.
Adapting one of the examples in their documentation, I was able to get:

[image: Tables with arrows besides]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = ->}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c}[last-col,margin]
A & B & C & \Vdotsfor{5}\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\hskip1cm
\NiceMatrixOptions{xdots={horizontal-labels,line-style = <-}}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c}[last-col,margin]
A & B & C & \Vdotsfor{5}\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that the argument for `\Vdotsfor` specifies how many rows the arrow stretches over.
If your table has more / fewer rows, you'll have to adjust the value.